# CSRF token missing or incorrect on POSTMAN

Tags: django, postman, csrf

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Post


class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'

from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView 
from django.urls import reverse_lazy 
from .forms import PostForm 
from .models import Post

class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'


class CreatePostView(CreateView): # new
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

How do I pass a request to the templates render method. I am getting a csrf token error on Postman while using POST method

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pre-request Script tab in Postman.
This code takes the csrf token from request headers and creates new response header with its value.

```js
if (pm.request.method !== 'GET' && !(pm.request.headers.has('x-csrf-token'))) {

  var csrfRequest = pm.request.clone();
  csrfRequest.method = 'GET';
  if (pm.request.method === 'POST') {
    csrfRequest.url = pm.request.url + '?$top=1';
  }

  csrfRequest.upsertHeader({
    key: 'x-csrf-token',
    value: 'fetch'
  });

  pm.sendRequest(csrfRequest, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      var csrfToken = res.headers.get('x-csrf-token');
      if (csrfToken) {
        pm.request.headers.upsert({
          key: 'x-csrf-token',
          value: csrfToken
        });
      } else {
        console.log('No csrf token fetched');
      }
    }
  });
}
```